# Problem to retrieve shortcut to FTP updates on Typo3 Website

Tags: website, ftp, webserver, plesk

I had a crash on my webserver and had to reinstall an update of the Website that was 2 years old (because nothing younger!). The Webserver is on Plesk 8.6 and the Website uses Typo3.
Now my problem is simple: before, I had a direct FTP access from every computer to "updates.myserver.de", that was actually a shortcut for "srv/www/myserver.de/httpdocs/..." etc. Now it seems the path doesn't work anymore, and every time I try to connect to "updates.myserver.de" i only open "myserver.de", and need to look for the folder then.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't think this is related to TYPO3? There's a lot of unrelated noise in the question, if you'd ask me... (You might also want to have a look at the preview while editing, or read http://superuser.com/editing-help Success!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your definition of "crash", if you had to reinstall Plesk from scratch, I do not think that `updates.` is a default location so you should go in to FTP settings and make sure that the settings are correct.

Comment: Yes, but the FTP settings in Plesk are reduced to "Login" and "password". And also the shell access, I don't know if I should change that. Could it be on my 1&1 hosting system?